# Angular yeoman spa click function not activating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman, single-page-application

Hopefully an easy one, App just built with the yo angular generator.
HTML(index)

```
<li ng-click="menuClick()"  class="active"><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
<li><a ng-href="#/about" ng-click="menuClick()" >About</a></li>
<li><a ng-href="#/">Contact</a></li>
```

app.js (config )

```
   angular
.module('testAngualrApp', [
'ngAnimate',
'ngCookies',
'ngResource',
'ngRoute',
'ngSanitize',
'ngTouch'
 ])
 .config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'main'
  })
  .when('/about', {
    templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
    controller: 'AboutCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'about'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
  });
```

JS (main)

```
angular.module('testAngualrApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
   this.awesomeThings = [
    'HTML5 Boilerplate',
     'AngularJS',
     'Karma'
    ];
    $scope.menuClick = function () {
       alert("yo");
   };
 });
```

EDIT $scope was not exported, no longer getting $scope undefined.

The above click event does not fire, I've tried ng-click before ng-href, just in case the page was getting redirected first, I've also tried using  **$scope**  instead of this, Why does the function not fire ?

Update: No erros, does not alert!

Comment: You need to debug this then. Do you see any errors in the Console? If you add `alert('yo');` in the code, outside any function, do you see it? (i.e. is your code even loaded)

Comment: ok, someone suggested using $scope instead of this, which did not work, I then realised i'm getting $scope undefined, only thing person has deleted answer...

Comment: That was me, and since you already tried what I suggested I saw no point leaving the answer. Anyway if $scope is not defined it means you don't have AngularJS working in the first place, so it most likely means you are not using that "yeoman" properly.

Comment: I get what ur saying, app is navigating around like a champ, an it's using ng href as in the HTML code, so i guess it must be there, there;s something silly going on..alright...thx

Comment: Show enough code that we can see the scope context. If you are using `controllerAs` syntax in view then it's clear why your code won't work. A demo that replicates problem is always helpful

Comment: As stated by others, you need to figure out if you're using the controllerAs syntax or not. In your HTML you might have a controller declaration (`ng-controller="..."`), or you might be using UI-Router in which case the controller is declared in your states configuration. Find the controller declaration and show it to us :)

Comment: Hi ng-controller is not defined in html anywhere, app.js is requiring...I'll post app.js

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `this` to declare methods in controller then it is assumed you are using `controllerAs` either in `ng-controller` or in router to define the alias for controller.

You must now use this alias object in the view to reference your controller methods and variables

Without knowing what your alias name is I will assume it is `vm` which is now being added to `ng-click` expression:

```
<li><a ng-href="#/products" ng-click="vm.menuClick()">Products</a></li>
```

Comment: Hi, so i tried prefixing, with vm, then in app.js it has entries like this   $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'main'
      })      <br> I tried 'MainCtrl.menuClick()' also 'main.method' same thing, nothing and no errors....getting closer

Comment: create a demo that replicates your issue in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue)

Comment: Also why do you need `ng-click` on `<a>` that has an href?

Comment: I'd like to be able to get at the click event so i can animate a moving bar under the <a> tags

Comment: but those tags will likely not be there die to the route change. Where is your demo?

Comment: I cant get the plunk working but i found and edited a very similar one, and it's working fine. might just ditch the yeoman spa, http://plnkr.co/edit/A43YoJ9mNwAJAk9ljarg?p=preview

Comment: I know, Im getting further slowly in the app.js file i;m getting angular is undefined, back soon!